# C++ OpenGL Shaders not working

Tags: c++, opengl, shader

I've just started learning c++ and I'm trying to make a program with shaders that draws a triangle with colors.

This is my vertex shader:

```
const GLchar* vertexSource =
"#version 150 core\n"
"in vec4 position;"
"in vec4 color;"
"out vec4 Color;"
"out vec4 gl_Position;"
"void main(){"
"   gl_Position = position;"
"   Color = color;"
"}";
```

and this is my fragment shader:

```
const GLchar* fragmentSource =
"#version 150 core\n"
"in vec4 Color;"
"out vec4 gl_FragColor"
"void main(){"
"    gl_FragColor = Color;"
"}";
```

I have a list of values for the co-ords and colors respectively:

```
float vertices[]{
    -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,1.0f,   1.0f,0.0f,0.0f,1.0f,
    1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,1.0f,    0.0f,1.0f,0.0f,1.0f,
    0.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f,1.0f,    0.0f,0.0f,1.0f,1.0f,
};
```

I initialise a 'vertex buffer object' and a 'vertex array object'

```
GLuint vao; //Initialise vertex array object
glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
glBindVertexArray(vao);

GLuint vbo; //Initialise vertex buffer object
glGenBuffers(1,&vbo);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,vbo);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,sizeof(vertices),vertices,GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

I compile a shader program:

```
GLuint vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
glShaderSource(vertexShader, 1, &vertexSource, NULL);
glCompileShader(vertexShader);

GLuint fragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
glShaderSource(fragmentShader, 1, &fragmentSource, NULL);
glCompileShader(fragmentShader);

GLuint shaderProgram = glCreateProgram();
glAttachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
glAttachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);

glUseProgram(shaderProgram);
```

I define some attributes for the shaders:

```
glBindAttribLocation(shaderProgram, 0, "position");
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(float), 0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

glBindAttribLocation(shaderProgram, 1 ,"color");
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(float), (void*)(4 * sizeof(float)));
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
```

and finally I draw the triangle in a 'do, while' loop

```
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
```

However, it doesn't print any triangles, but instead just shows a black screen.

I got most of this code from tutorials online, and I'm trying to rewrite everything out to understand how everything works.

Could anyone see where I went wrong? Any advice would be greatly appreciated :)

Edit:

I've added some code to check for errors:

```
if (status == GL_FALSE)
{
    GLint infoLogLength;
    glGetShaderiv(shaderProgram, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &infoLogLength);

    GLchar* strInfoLog = new GLchar[infoLogLength + 1];
    glGetProgramInfoLog(shaderProgram, infoLogLength, NULL, strInfoLog);

    std::cout << strInfoLog;
    delete[] strInfoLog;
}
```

...but nothing prints

Comment: First, `/n` is not the same as `\n`.  Second, you should check for error messages when you compile the shader.  Use `glGetShaderInfoLog​()`.

Comment: You didn't state what you're having trouble with, compilation errors? drawing problems?

Comment: it just doesnt draw out, I get a blank screen when i run the program

Comment: Right, check for errors.  Checking for errors is easy.  Asking for help on the internet is a waste of everybody's time if you are not checking for errors.

Comment: @AdrianNgai: If you need to add stuff to your question, use the "edit" button.

Comment: I've added some code to my loop:     
        `    if (status == GL_FALSE)
    {
        GLint infoLogLength;
        glGetShaderiv(shaderProgram, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &infoLogLength);

        GLchar* strInfoLog = new GLchar[infoLogLength + 1];
        glGetShaderInfoLog(shaderProgram, infoLogLength, NULL, strInfoLog);

        std::cout << strInfoLog;
        delete[] strInfoLog;
    }`
but nothing prints, so not sure if there's no error, or I've coded it wrong?

Comment: @AdrianNgai I would expect that nothing prints because A) `glGetShaderInfoLog` doesn't print anything, ever. B) it's `glGetShaderInfoLog` for shaders and `glGetProgramInfoLog` for shader programs.

Comment: any idea how to print the data from glGetShaderProgramInfoLog? I've changed it to glGetProgramInfoLog and still nothing happens

Comment: Also I suggest you put your shader code in a separate file and read that. Putting shader code in string literals inside C/C++ code is not very readable.

Comment: @AdrianNgai: What Jan Henke said. I suggest you use an existing and tested shader loading code. I invite you to use the one I developed. There's no pure repository for it, but the latest iteration can be found in a small test program of mine: https://github.com/datenwolf/pointoverdrawbench/tree/master/shaderloader – see https://github.com/datenwolf/pointoverdrawbench/blob/master/solid.c for how it's used. Also feel free to make use of my `debug_gl` wrappers which will give you plenty of dignostics output on OpenGL calls.

Comment: what sort of code would I use in order to read from a separate file, and where would I put that file?

Comment: @AdrianNgai: See the links I gave you. `shaderloader` is the kind of code you're looking for. And you should also add lots of diagnostics to the rest of your OpenGL calls, see `debuggl` in what I've linked.

Answer (score 1):

`gl_Position` is a pre defined built in variable and your GLSL compiler surely is complaining about trying to redefining it and errors out. Similarly `gl_FragColor` is in the reserved namespace.

Of course your code lacks queries of the *shader* info log, so you don't see that compiler output; your addendum just queries the program linker log.

The solution is probably as easy as simply omitting the `out vec4 gl_Position` and `out vec4 gl_FragColor` from your shader sources.

Comment: I also add that there is a missing ";" on this line: "out vec4 gl_FragColor", so this will probably cause fragment compilation to fail.

Comment: weird; I've fixed both errors, and still nothing happens. perhaps something else?

Comment: @AdrianNgai: Add more diagnostics. I commented in your original question and in the repository linked you can find a few diagnostics goodies.